# Concurrency: Condition.awaitNanos() not releasing lock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, conditional-statements

In my program i am using a Condition object created from a

```
private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

like so:

```
private static final Condition operationFinished = MyClass.lock.newCondition();
```

Occasionally (as it is always happening with concurrency problems) i encounter following behavior:

1. Thread1 aquires the lock
2. Thread1 calls `operationFinished.awaitNanos()` - this should suspend Thread1 and release the lock.
3. Thread2 tries to aquire the same lock, but debugging output shows that Thread1 is still holding the lock!

According to documentation this behavior is impossible, because upon `awaitNanos()` Thread1 first releases the lock and then suspends.
If it didn't release the lock, then it would not suspend, therefore Thread2 could never even get a possibility to try to get hold on the lock.

Has anybody experienced something similar? This errors happens once in 100 times - but still it indicates that I am either not using the concurrency-utilities in a proper way, or that there is some kind of bug in the java.utils.concurrent.* package (which i doubt).

**UPDATE:**

In response to Peters answer:

I observe following behavior: Apparently the 2 threads deadlock each other. I can see that Thread2 blocks (waiting for the lock) and at the same time `awaitNanos()` in Thread1 never times out.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are viewing this information, I have seen many examples of where multiple threads `wait()` on an object still say they are all holding the same lock.  It may be that the stack trace or monitoring is mis-leading.

Say you have thread1 which is holding the lock, but in awaitNanos(), you have Thread2 which is trying to obtain the lock(), but sometimes Thread3 is holding the lock as well....

I would do a `jstack -l {pid}` to check all the threads which might be holding the lock.

If a lock deadlocks, awaitLock (nor wait()) won't return as it must acquire the lock before doing so. (Unless it is interrupted)

Comment: Thx for your response! Updated my answer with further info: The lock is definitely still held by Thread1, since i can see Thread2 blocking on `lock()`.

Comment: And Thread1 is definitively in awaitNanos() ?  Can you show us the stack trace for these two threads and any other thread which might be holding the lock. e.g. from `jstack`

Comment: I realized that there might be the possibility of Thread2 trying to aquire the lock, when Thread1 is still not in awaitNanos(). But even in this case, Thread2 would block until Thread1 calls awaitNanos() and then grab the lock...

Comment: I am going to post the output of jstack next time this error occurs, unfortunately its not really reproducible :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the wait time hasn't finished? If you wait for a short period of time (a few hundred nanoseconds, for example), the wait time could expire before Thread2 can fully start, in which case Thread1 might be reactivated first.

Comment: I am throwing an exception if wait time expires, but there is no exception when this problem occurs and no more debugging output either (which should still be output in case Thread1 continues after the await()).

Comment: Are you releasing the lock before throwing the exception? And remember that if the thread throwing the exception isn't the main thread, then it could bubble up the call stack on that thread and then disappear unless you've set the uncaught exception handler for the thread.

Comment: The point is, that in the current case the exception is never thrown, so awaitNanos() is never returning...seems like Thread1 and Thread2 are deadlocking each other..